# Synchronous way of handling asynchronous function, two level deep

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, async-await, synchronous

I am looping over an array to update its values using returned value from called function which `internally calls an asynchronous function`.

I need to handle asynchronous function in synchronous way which is not being directly called. **This is [replication of scenario](https://jsfiddle.net/sujit77/p6bbkx7h/)**.

```
function condition(){
    // Code of this function is not accessible to me.
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        setTimeout(function(){
            if(parseInt(Math.random() * 100) % 2){
                resolve(true);
            }
            else{
                reject(false)
            }
        }, 1000)
    });
}

async function delayIncrease(value){
    var choice = await condition(); 

    if(choice) { return ++value; }
    else { return --value; }
}

// Start calling functions
dataArr = [1,2,3,4,5];
for(var i in dataArr){
    dataArr[i] = delayIncrease(dataArr[i]);
}
```

**If possible, I would like to have the solution in above structure mentioned.**

I have achieved the desired result by `adding other function` and passing `"index" + "new_value"` as parameters. This function directly `modifies original array` and produces desired result. **[Working example](https://jsfiddle.net/sujit77/r7nys2xe/)**.

```
function condition(){
    // Code of this function is not accessible to me.
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        setTimeout(function(){
            if(parseInt(Math.random() * 100) % 2){
                resolve(true);
            }
            else{
                reject(false)
            }
        }, 1000)
    });
}

function delayIncrease(value, index){            
    condition().then(
        function(){ updateData(++value, index) },
        function(){ updateData(--value, index) }
    )
}

function updateData(value, index){
    dataArr[index] = value;          
}

dataArr = [1,2,3,4,5];
for(var i in dataArr){
    dataArr[i] = delayIncrease(dataArr[i], i);
}
```

Please provide solution for this requirement in best possible way. Possible solution in Angular 4 way is also appriciated. I thought of writing it in normal JavaScript form as `Observables` behave nearly same.

I followed [this Medium page](https://medium.com/@bluepnume/learn-about-promises-before-you-start-using-async-await-eb148164a9c8) and [http://exploringjs.com](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_promises.html)

Comment: What is the expected outcome?

Comment: **@FCin** - Expected outcome should be decision capability depending upon Promise's approval/rejection. I just want to perform different operation on the `original array`. Desired behaviour is exactly same which I have managed in [solution 2](https://jsfiddle.net/sujit77/r7nys2xe/). But I think there should be better solution than that.

Comment: If the code works, then I think this question is more suited for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: **@FCin** - The [1st solution/way](https://jsfiddle.net/sujit77/p6bbkx7h/) doesn't work. I just managed to write 2nd solution which is not optimal one. Shall I still raise Code review request?

Comment: It doesn't make much sense to have your functions be async when there is no async processing.

Answer (score 2):

Your `condition` function does not really fulfill the promise with either true or false, it does randomly fulfill or *reject* the promise. Instead of branching on a boolean, you will need to [catch that "error"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44663864/1048572):

```
async function delayIncrease(value) {
    try {
        await condition(); 
        return ++value;
    } catch(e) {
        return --value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
var condition = async () =>
  (parseInt(Math.random() * 100) % 2)
    ? true
    : false

var delayIncrease =  async (value) =>
  (await condition())
    ? ++value
    : --value

var dataArr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
// Start calling functions
Promise.all(
  dataArr.map(
    delayIncrease
  )
)
.then(
  resolve => console.log("results:",resolve)
  ,reject => console.warn("rejected:",reject)
)
```

Once something is async you have to make the entire call stack prior to that function async. If a function calls an async function that that function returns an async value and so does the one calling it and calling it and calling it ...

More info on javascript async and why can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47678417/1641941).

Since the example provided doesn't have any async api's in there you don't need to do it async:

```
var condition = () =>
  (parseInt(Math.random() * 100) % 2)
    ? true
    : false

var delayIncrease =  (value) =>
  (condition())
    ? ++value
    : --value

var dataArr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
// Start calling functions
dataArr.map(
  delayIncrease
)
```

**[update]**

When you mutate an array of objects and cosole.log it you may not see the values **as they actually were** when you log it but you see the values **as they are right now** (this is a "bug" in console.log).

Consider the following:

```
var i = -1,arr=[];
while(++i<1){
  arr[i]={};
  arr[i]["name"+i]=i
}

var process = (index) =>
  arr[index]["name"+index]++;

arr.forEach(
  (item,index) =>
    Promise.resolve(index)
    .then(process)
);
console.log("obj at the moment you are looking at it:",arr)
console.log("obj at the moment it is logged:",JSON.stringify(arr))
```

When you expand `obj at the moment you are looking at it` you see that name0 property of the first element changed to 1.

However; look at `obj at the moment it is logged:` and see the actual value of the first element in the array. It has `name0` of 0.

You may think that the that code runs asynchronous functions in a synchronous way by mutating the object(s) in an array, but you actually experience a "bug" in console.log

Comment: Your code works perfectly, but codes of `condition()` is not accessible to me. It should `always return Promise` And also, I need to modify the original array. It is an array of objects(I made it plain to reduce code complexity in examples)

Comment: @SujitKumarSingh so the `contition` function returns a promise? Then you can use the first example. I don't see a good reason to mutate an array (that is globally scoped in your example) in resolve handlers but I do see plenty of reasons not to do so.

Comment: @SujitKumarSingh Updated my answer, I don't know why you think that mutating an array makes the functions synchronous but can think of one reason (in the answer). Please read the following (or at least watch the video link) to have some understanding of why promises are used and how they are used.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47664598/async-function-not-returning-value-but-console-log-does-how-to-do/47678417#47678417