# how to pass resolved value

Tags: javascript, promise

what's wrong with this `Promise` using?

```js
const count_elems = function(c){
  const elems = c.getElementsByTagName('p');
  console.log(elems.length);
};

const handler = function(){
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
     const cont = document.getElementById('cont');
     const p = document.createElement('p');
     for (let i=100000; i--;){
        cont.appendChild(p.cloneNode());
     }
     return resolve(cont);
  })
}

const test = function(){
  handler()
    .then(count_elems(c))
    .catch(function(e){console.log(e)});
};

document.getElementById('but')
  .addEventListener('click', test);
```

```html
 <div id="cont"></div>
  <button id="but">click me</button>
```

Comment: what issue you are facing?

Comment: There is no need for the promises, there is no asynchronous code anywhere. Are you expecting the promise to run on it's own thread? That is simply not the case though. Why JS uses promises is explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47678417/1641941

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the `c` in the `then` function and then pass into the `count_elems` function. Also remove the `return` before the `resolve`, you don't need that.

`.then(c => count_elems(c))` or just `.then(count_elems)` without function call.

```js
const count_elems = function(c){
   const elems = c.getElementsByTagName('p');
   console.log(elems.length);
};

const handler = function() {

   return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      const cont = document.getElementById('cont');
      const p = document.createElement('p');
      
      for (let i=100000; i--;){
         cont.appendChild(p.cloneNode());
      }
     
      resolve(cont);
  });
  
}

const test = function() {
   handler().then(c => count_elems(c))
            .catch(e => console.log(e));
};

document.getElementById('but')
        .addEventListener('click', test);
```

```html
<div id="cont"></div>
<button id="but">click me</button>
```

Comment: code is works, but I expected that the container `cont` will be full...

Comment: You mean  `p` to be visible ? See the updated part. You need to create `p` in the for loop.

Comment: not exactly visible but I mean that loop should finish before Promise resolving

Comment: It is working like that. Loop is finished then Promise is resolved

Comment: It is that IDE issue. If you will decrease the amount if the loop, you can see that it works correct.

Comment: just checked in the browser, it seems that you are right

Answer (score 1):

`.then(count_elems(c))` should be `.then(count_elems)`