# Get value in promise array

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native, promise, asyncstorage

I'm using AsyncStorage from react-native to get and store data for my app. I successfully store data via AsyncStorage but when I try to getItem from AsyncStorage it

```
Promise {_40: 0, _65: 1, _55: "30", _72: null}
```

How to get "30" value? I tried .json and Promise.resolved to get the data, both not working.

```
react-native: "0.47.1"
android version: 6
```

Comment: Use Promise.all(), refer to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Answer (score 4):

if you want to get value from it you must do this :

you have 2 ways :

1.using `async/await` as code below :

```
async function(){
  var a = await someFunction(your_input);
  console.log(a)
}
```

2.using `.then()`

```
someFuntion(your_input).then((result)=>{
  console.log(result)
})
```

Answer (score 2):

this is solution:

```
    var data=''
    Promise.resolve(your_promise).then(value=>{
    console.log('value:',value)
    data=value;
    })
```

Comment: try to add more description of the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```js
var myPromise = Promise.resolve({_40: 0, _65: 1, _55: "30", _72: null});
myPromise.then(
  value=>{
    console.log("get value._55",value._55);
  }
)
```

More on why promises are used and some info on how to use them can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47678417/1641941).