# Alternative of jquery ajax async false

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Is there any alternative code of `jquery` `ajax async` false ?

I should code like below:

```
func1(){
    var result = false;
    $.getJSON("URL", function(data){
        result = data;
    });

    return result;
}
```

How about adding done() method after `$.getJSON()?` then the code flows as `func1() -> getJSON() -> done() -> func1() -> return` ?

Any suggestion?

Comment: Callbacks, promises, async/await. plenty of tutorials for all of them. You can't return data from inside an async function like getJSON without making it sync by using the async = false flag.

Comment: there is no alternative if you want `func1` to return a value synchronously - which you should avoid anyway

Comment: I see.... then I have to approach another way..

Comment: Functions you write should be non blocking, that means they have to return a value immediately so you can't wait for a network request to finish so you can return the result. You can return a promise of the network result. It is explained in more detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47678417/1641941).

Comment: @HMR thank you really! that is an alternative way that I want. I didn't know about async function and promise. Now I am digging in promise reference. :)