# Updating items using batch - how to properly handle error and success?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to update multiple items at once, and I have to make a network request for each item.  I am using fetch for making the request.

Here's an example of what I mean:

```
const updateItems = items => items.forEach(item => api.create(item))
```

`api.create` might look something like this:

```
create: item => fetch(url, config(item)).then(handleErr).then(handleRes)
```

How can I make ensure that I am batching all things successfully?  Each `create` is a promise, but I am having trouble using Promise.all as a wrapper because I get the following error:  `Cannot read property 'Symbol(Symbol.iterator)' of undefined`

However, the updates are successful, so I'm doing something wrong!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should be: `fetch(url, config(item)).then(handleRes).catch(handleErr)` And the code calling your method should use `Promise.all` with `items.map` so the calling code can do something with the result (failed and succeeded).

An example of that (here `updateItems` will not catch any errors, the calling code will):

```
const Fail = function(details){this.details=details;},
isFail = item => (item && item.constructor)===Fail;
Promise.all(
  items.map(//map array of items to array of promises that don't reject
    item =>
      updateItems(item)
      .then(
        undefined,//do not handle resolve yet
        //when you handle the reject this ".then" will return
        //  a promise that RESOLVES to the value returned below (new Fail([item,err]))
        err=>new Fail([item,err])
      )
  )
)
.then(
  responses => {
    console.log("failed requests:");
    console.log(
      responses.filter(//only Fail type
        isFail
      )
    );
    console.log("resolved requests:");
    console.log(
      responses.filter(//anything not Fail type
        response=>!isFail(response)
      )
    );
  }
);
```

That code comes from the [following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47678417/1641941) explaining promises.