# Unable to handle promise failure inside other promise

Tags: javascript, promise

I'm trying to use 2 promises, the second promise depends on the first one. And a 3 promise depends on both promises. But when first promise fails I get this error in the second promise:

UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2): TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null

This is my code:

```
var Asset  = require('../models/index').Asset;
var Price = require('../models/index').Price;

var currency = req.params.currency;

var values = { 
                where: { slugify_url: currency },                    
            };

// get asset information 
var promisse_asset = Asset.findOne(values); 


// get prices information on this asset
var promisse_prices = promisse_asset.then(function(asset) {

    console.log(asset); // outputs null
    // some processing
    if (!!asset) {
        ...  


});


return Promise.all([promisse_asset, promisse_prices]).then(function([asset, results]) {
    ...
```

How can I fix this? How can I handle when I don't find an Asset in my database?

Comment: You seem to simply be missing a `catch` (or second `then` argument). Without it, you get that _"unhandled promise rejection"_ error

Comment: @Phil I put a catch after the first promise, but it seems it is not entering in the catch condition. How should I do it?

Comment: Ah, so the first promise is resolving successfully, just with a `null` value. You should throw an error in that case to cause the promise to fail. That one would need to be caught in the `Promise.all` promise

Comment: @Phil thanks! I added the catch to the third promise and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a situation where you want to batch process promises and get all the results **including rejected ones** with `Promise.all`. How you can do that is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47678417/1641941) (last code block).

There is a situation where you want to catch a rejecting promise on the queue and not on the stack without getting warnings (soon to be deprecated and getting errors). How you can do that is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47924297/1641941).

Or you just wanted to reject a promise because the resolve value is not what you expected, you can throw as provided by Phil or return a `Promise.reject("Something should not be null")`.