# Functional Programming - What's the best way to keep a reference to a function's result for later use?

Tags: javascript, node.js, functional-programming

I'm new to functional programming (doesn't know any fp languages except for javascript) and I have a code practice issue that has been bugging me for a while. Sorry for the generic title, I hope this example will clarify the question:

```
// right to left
compose(
  useXAgain,
  ...
  doSomethingElse,
  useX,
  getX
)(input);
```

What's the best way to pass the output of getX to useXAgain? I can think of 3 ways to do it:

1. Save it in a variable

   ```
   let X = undefined;
   compose(
     useXAgain(X),
     ...
     doSomethingElse,
     res => { X = res; return useX(X); },
     getX
   )(input);
   ```
2. Pass it along the chain until it reaches useXAgain

   ```
   compose(
     ({X, res}) => useXAgain(X, res),
     ...
     ({X, res}) => ({ X, res: doSomethingElse(res) }),
     X => ({X, res: useX(X) }),
     getX
   )(input);
   ```
3. Put everything after getX into a new function

   ```
   const afterGetX = X => compose(
     useXAgain(X),
     ...
     doSomethingElse,
     useX
   )(X);

   compose(
     afterGetX,
     getX
   )(input);
   ```

I don't like any of those ways, none of them are elegant and make code messy. Please share what your think is the best way to do this.

Comment: In ECMAScript you can compose an array of functions to a new function, since ES is not statically typed you can have an array like `a => b => c => d` when you need to save `b` (result of `a => b` to a last function `(b,d)=>e` then you can use closure or use a helper called `thread` like [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48677470/1641941)

Comment: Since function composition is a sequence of unary, pure functions I'd say split the composition. Nothing to be ashamed of.