# Why async function return 'zone object'

Tags: angular, typescript, async-await, zone

this question is a little related with [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48670283/860099). Here we have following code in ANGULAR:

```
private async createFloor(name) 
{
    let newFloorData = { 
        floorName: name,
        percent: 0,
        requestSubscription: null,
        finish: false,
        deleted: false,
    };

    ...

    return newFloorData;
}

public async addFloor(event) 
{
     let newFloorData = this.createFloor('test name');
     debugger;
     ...
}
```

And in debugger chrome debugger when i look on `newFloorData` I get following information:

> ZoneAwarePromise
>
> __zone_symbol__state : true
>
> __zone_symbol__value : {percent: 0, requestSubscription: null, finish: false, deleted: false}
>
> **proto** : Object

However if I add `await` in `addFloor` function:

```
public async addFloor(event) 
{
     let newFloorData = await this.createFloor('test name');
     debugger;
     ...
}
```

In debugger I just get newFloorData object returned by `createFloor` (which is intuitive).

**Question**: Why? What mechanism is behind this behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular uses zone.js to patch almost all async APIs. 
It does this to get notified when an async action happened and then triggers a change detection run.

See also

- https://angular.io/api/core/NgZone
- https://github.com/angular/zone.js