# Most appropriate error-handling strategy for parsing in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, error-handling

JavaScript is multi-paradigm and provides (at least) 3 different error-handling strategies for synchronous code.

I have seen this question asked in the context of `async` functions, for which promises are clearly recommended, but what about synchronous functions?

One example would be parsing. Suppose I have a function for parsing strings into integers. This function will fail in the case of a malformed input, but how should I model this?

**1. Try-catch Style**

```
const f = () => {
  throw new Error('Something has gone wrong. ');
};

// Usage
try {
  console.log(f()); 
} catch (error) {
  console.error(error); 
}
```

**2. Callback Style**

```
const f = (callback) => {
  callback(new Error('Something has gone wrong. '), null);
};

// Usage
f((error, result) => {
  if (error) {
    console.error(error);
  } else {
    console.log(result);
  }
});
```

**3. FP Style (also seen in Go)**

```
const f = () => {
  return {
    error: new Error('Something has gone wrong. '), 
    result: null
  };
};

// Usage
const { error, result } = f();

if (error) {
  console.error(error); 
} else {
  console.log(result);
}
```

Comment: Depends on your design pattern I suppose. This seems like an opinion based question. I personally design my handling of synchronous code using the 2nd method if that helps but that does not mean there's anything wrong with any other method.

Comment: Opinion based but I'd prefer promise over callback so 2 is out. Try catch I only use when calling code that can throw (so not my own) And 3 looks a bit like [railway orientated programming](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/rop/) which is also kind of what promises do for you, you can skip a bunch of stacked `.then` and `.catch` something in the end if anything went wrong. So my vote goes to 3. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47678417/1641941) for promises that don't fail if you need to do a `Promise.all` but rather not go the `.catch` route when one or more items fail.

Comment: @HMR Are promises really appropriate fron non-async code though?

Comment: @Adriani6 This is a broad question, I suppose, but the design implications of each approach (i.e. what they make easy and what they make hard) are sufficiently diverse and objective.

Comment: Probably nr 3 is good for synchronous railway orientated programming.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid (rolling your own) callback style, it makes it unnecessary complicated (and you still need the `if`).

Synchronous exceptions are the go-to solution. They are common, easy to understand, and have simple syntax.

If you like functional programming, you can also use an appropriate data structure to represent the possible error in your type signature. However, you would not just return an object literal, you would use a library that implements the `Either` datatype with all appropriate methods. [There](http://folktale.origamitower.com/api/v2.1.0/en/folktale.result.html) [are](https://github.com/JanVanRyswyck/either.js) [quite](https://monet.github.io/monet.js/#either) [a few](https://sanctuary.js.org/#either-type)…