# Object Promise, impossible to get value

Tags: javascript, object, asynchronous, promise

I have some asynchronous function:

```
async global(){
    return 'Test success'
}
```

I call this in my hook and it must be fulfilled:

```
const Controller = use('App/Controllers/Http/Controller')

View.global('ShowGlobal', async () => {
    const call = new Controller()
    const info = await call.global()
    console.log(info)
    return info
})
```

At the same time i am getting correct console.log with result 'Test success', but return gives me constantly [object Promise]
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you need to `await ShowGlobal()` when you call it

Comment: your options are.... use the promise, or abandon ship. time travel would be required to avoid needing the promise (that or making whatever is asking for the value `async` as well.)

Comment: [The return value of an async function is always wrapped inside a promise.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function#return_value)

Comment: All `async` functions return a promise.  The caller of an `async` function MUST use `.then()` or `await` to get the value from that promise.  The value you return from the `async` function becomes the resolved value of the promise that the function returns.  This is how all `async` functions work - there is no other way around it.

Answer (score -2):

(This is an answer I found)

The code you write in JavaScript is run on one thread, that means that if your code could actually wait for something it will block any of your other code from getting executed. The event loop of JavaScript is explained very well in this video and if you like to read in this page.

A good example of blocking code in the browser is alert("cannot do anything until you click ok");. Alert blocks everything, the user can't even scroll or click on anything in the page and your code also blocks from executing.

```
Promise.resolve(22)
.then(x=>alert("blocking")||"Hello World")
.then(
  x=>console.log(
    "does not resolve untill you click ok on the alert:",
    x
  )
);
```

Run that in a console and you see what I mean by blocking.

This creates a problem when you want to do something that takes time. In other frameworks you'd use a thread or processes but there is no such thing in JavaScript (technically there is with web worker and fork in node but that's another story and usually far more complicated than using async api's).

So when you want to make a http request you can use fetch but fetch takes some time to finish and your function should not block (has to return something as fast as possible). This is why fetch returns a promise.

Note that fetch is implemented by browser/node and does run in another thread, only code you write runs in one thread so starting a lot of promises that only run code you write will not speed up anything but calling native async api's in parallel will.

Before promises async code used callbacks or would return an observable object (like XmlHttpRequest) but let's cover promises since you can convert the more traditional code to a promise anyway.

A promise is an object that has a then function (and a bunch of stuff that is sugar for then but does the same), this function takes 2 parameters.

Resolve handler: A function that will be called by the promise when the promise resolves (has no errors and is finished). The function will be passed one argument with the resolve value (for http requests this usually is the response).
Reject handler: A function that will be called by the promise when the promise rejects (has an error). This function will be passed one argument, this is usually the error or reason for rejection (can be a string, number or anything).
Converting callback to promise.

The traditional api's (especially nodejs api's) use callbacks:

```
traditionalApi(
  arg
  ,function callback(err,value){ 
    err ? handleFail(err) : processValue(value);
  }
);
```

This makes it difficult for the programmer to catch errors or handle the return value in a linear way (from top to bottom). It gets even more impossible to try and do things parallel or throttled parallel with error handling (impossible to read).

You can convert traditional api's to promises with new Promise

```
const apiAsPromise = arg =>
  new Promise(
    (resolve,reject)=>
      traditionalApi(
        arg,
        (err,val) => (err) ? reject(err) : resolve(val)
      )
  )
async await
```

This is what's called syntax sugar for promises. It makes promise consuming functions look more traditional and easier to read. That is if you like to write traditional code, I would argue that composing small functions is much easier to read. For example, can you guess what this does?:

```
const handleSearch = search =>
  compose([
    showLoading,
    makeSearchRequest,
    processRespose,
    hideLoading
  ])(search)
  .then(
    undefined,//don't care about the resolve
    compose([
      showError,
      hideLoading
    ])
  );
```

Anayway; enough ranting. The important part is to understand that async await doesn't actually start another thread, async functions always return a promise and await doesn't actually block or wait. It's syntax sugar for someFn().then(result=>...,error=>...) and looks like:

```
async someMethod = () =>
  //syntax sugar for:
  //return someFn().then(result=>...,error=>...)
  try{
    const result = await someFn();
    ...
   }catch(error){
     ...
   }
}
```

The examples allways show try catch but you don't need to do that, for example:

```
var alwaysReject = async () => { throw "Always returns rejected promise"; };
alwaysReject()
.then(
  x=>console.log("never happens, doesn't resolve")
  ,err=>console.warn("got rejected:",err)
);
```

Any error thrown or await returning a rejected promise will cause the async function to return a rejected promise (unless you try and catch it). Many times it is desirable to just let it fail and have the caller handle errors.

Catching errors could be needed when you want the promise to succeed with a special value for rejected promises so you can handle it later but the promise does not technically reject so will always resolve.

An example is Promise.all, this takes an array of promises and returns a new promise that resolves to an array of resolved values or reject when any one of them rejects. You may just want to get the results of all promises back and filter out the rejected ones:

```
const Fail = function(details){this.details=details;},
isFail = item => (item && item.constructor)===Fail;
Promise.all(
  urls.map(//map array of urls to array of promises that don't reject
    url =>
      fetch(url)
      .then(
        undefined,//do not handle resolve yet
        //when you handle the reject this ".then" will return
        //  a promise that RESOLVES to the value returned below (new Fail([url,err]))
        err=>new Fail([url,err])
      )
  )
)
.then(
  responses => {
    console.log("failed requests:");
    console.log(
      responses.filter(//only Fail type
        isFail
      )
    );
    console.log("resolved requests:");
    console.log(
      responses.filter(//anything not Fail type
        response=>!isFail(response)
      )
    );
  }
);
```

Comment: Copying and pasting from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47664598/async-function-not-returning-value-but-console-log-does-how-to-do is bad form

Comment: If the whole answer applies marking the question as duplicate is probably a better option. If part of the answer applies, at least use a quote block (so people know someone else wrote it) and link the original answer to give proper credit.